# How to update xml attributes without using a loop with the xml2 R package

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I have an xml object that I would like to update using R's xml2 package. There are two things I generally need to do:

1. Update text inside nodes `<c>{text}</c>`
2. Update attributes of nodes `<c name={text}/>`

I'd like to avoid looping over the xml structure because that is significantly slower than identifying the node set and assigning an entire vector of values to it at once.

```
xml <- read_xml("<root>
        <c name='test' db_name='TEST'><d>This is the column desc</d></c>
        <c name='test2' db_name='TEST2'><d>This is the column desc</d></c>
        <c name='test3' db_name='TEST3'><d>This is the column desc</d></c>
    </root>")

df <- data.frame(
    db_name = c("TEST2", "TEST", "TEST3"), 
    desc = c("New desc!", "You want this desc", "GOOD VECTOR"),
    disp_name = c("OKAY", "NOW", "HAPPY"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

#### We are GOOD on #1

```
c_nodes           <- xml %>% xml_find_all("//c")
c_db_names        <- c_nodes %>% xml_find_all("@db_name") %>% xml_text    
xml_text(c_nodes) <- df$desc[match(c_db_names, df$db_name)]
```

#### BAD on #2

```
disp_names <- df$disp_name[match(c_db_names, df$db_name)]

for (i in seq_along(c_nodes)) {
  xml_attr(c_nodes[i], "name") <- disp_names[i]
}
```

When I try `xml_attr(c_nodes, "name") <- df$disp_name[match(c_db_names, df$db_name)]`, I get the following error:

`Error in node_set_attr(x$node, name = attr, nsMap = ns, value) : 
  expecting a single value`

If I provide a single value it updates the entire node set with that one value, but I need to make different updates to each node attribute. Thus, I'm using a loop, but I want to replace it with a vectorized equivalent to produce this:

```
{xml_document}
<root>
[1] <c name="NOW" db_name="TEST">\n  <d>You want this desc</d>\n</c>
[2] <c name="OKAY" db_name="TEST2">\n  <d>New desc!</d>\n</c>
[3] <c name="HAPPY" db_name="TEST3">\n  <d>GOOD VECTOR</d>\n</c>
```

Comment: did you try xml_set_attr?

Comment: yep, it returns the same error

Comment: The set functions seem to be the same as `xml_attr() <-` except the set functions have the assignment as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xml_set_attrs is the correct function to use, but you must pass in a list of named character vectors for the value parameter. You can create this list using an apply function, and then pass it into the function as follows:

```
new_attrs<-lapply(df$disp_name[match(c_db_names, df$db_name)], 
                  function(x) {
                                names(x)<- "name"
                                x
                               })

xml_set_attrs(c_nodes, new_attrs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tom, but I just want to clarify one thing. The `xml_set_attrs` is not required to answer this question. You can also use `xml_attrs(c_nodes) <- new_attrs`